# How to Set the Configuration File to current dll.config

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

When I start my exe , the configuration file is set to mypp.exe.config.

After certian point , I want it to point to mydll.config.

I am trying with:

```
var configPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
var Location = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile = config.FilePath;
```

But when I set a break point to see, the Configuration file is still set to myapp.exe.config.

What's missing?

Comment: I do not believe the configuration file can be changed after the app has started running.

Comment: I am also stuck at the same thing...did you find any way @simsons ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`AppDomain.SetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", config.FilePath);
```

I can't find any documentation for that, but it worked for me.